# Using refresh token with Google directory service API

Tags: python, google-api, google-admin-sdk, google-directory-api

Is there any way to use a refresh token with Google directory service API?
I couldn't find any examples how to do that (I'm using Python).
I'm looking for something similar to the following code (this works for Google Adwords API), with previosly set credentials:

```
oauth2_client = oauth2.GoogleRefreshTokenClient(
    CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET, REFRESH_TOKEN)

adwords_client = adwords.AdWordsClient(
    DEVELOPER_TOKEN, oauth2_client, USER_AGENT, CLIENT_CUSTOMER_ID)

self.managed_customer_service = adwords_client.GetService(
    'ManagedCustomerService', version='v201402')
```

For Directory API I found just the following code snippet, but I have no idea how I could use a refresh token with it:

```
flow = OAuth2WebServerFlow(CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET, OAUTH_SCOPE, REDIRECT_URI)
authorize_url = flow.step1_get_authorize_url()
print 'Go to the following link in your browser: ' + authorize_url
code = raw_input('Enter verification code: ').strip()
credentials = flow.step2_exchange(code)

# Create an httplib2.Http object and authorize it with our credentials
http = httplib2.Http()
http = credentials.authorize(http)

self.directory_service = build('admin', 'directory_v1', http=http)
```

My final goal is to authorize my application using just the refresh token and without having to open the browser, login and get a new token each time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Python client library can automatically store, load, and refresh credentials if you use a Storage object. The [Gmail API Python Quickstart sample](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/quickstart-python#step_3_set_up_the_sample) shows how to use a file storage, which saves the credentials to disk. Here are the relevant lines of code:

```
from oauth2client.file import Storage
from oauth2client.tools import run

...

# Location of the credentials storage file
STORAGE = Storage('gmail.storage')

...

# Try to retrieve credentials from storage or run the flow to generate them
credentials = STORAGE.get()
if credentials is None or credentials.invalid:
  credentials = run(flow, STORAGE, http=http)
```

There are [additional storage classes](https://github.com/google/oauth2client/tree/master/oauth2client) built into the client library, or you can extend the [`Storage` base class](https://github.com/google/oauth2client/blob/master/oauth2client/client.py#L297) to implement you own.